# CORS issue No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, fonts, amazon-s3, cors

I have my fonts in a subdomain like `static.example.com` Today the fonts aren't displayed in Chrome —and in Firefox as well— and this error appeared in the dev tools:

«Font from origin 'http://static.example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.»

I already have this code in the subdomain `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Also if I try `curl -I http://static.example.com/fonts/pfcentrosanspro-reg-webfont.eot` in the terminal I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 17:20:50 GMT
Content-Type: font/eot
Content-Length: 26403
Connection: keep-alive
X-Accel-Version: 0.01
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 17:49:42 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 17:20:50 GMT
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST
```

But the error persists, I have moved the fonts to a bucket in Amazon S3 CDN with this code:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

No luck, the error is still there —the fonts doesn't load and the CORS error is displayed—, I even have modified the Nginx config file without results!

Am I doing something wrong? this is driving me nuts.

The site is a Wordpress blog with W3 Total Caché plugin

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Definitely sounds like a caching problem. Since cURL headers are correct, they should be correct in the browser request as well. Did you disable browser cache in Chrome / Firefox? You can do that in Chrome Developer Tool Settings.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Some browsers don't like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

You should set this to the domain of the originating request. I've struggled a lot with similar issues, and finally landed on the below solution (PHP, but you'll get the idea).

```
$origin=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']:$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);        
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1');
```

This code will accept all requests from all domains. This could be insecure. You'd probably want to check the requests against a whitelist of accepted domains.